# Array of arrays variable losing structure / brackets when rendered to EJS

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, ejs

Please help! I've spent hours trying to figure out why my array of arrays variable is flattened out & loses brackets when templated over to an ejs file - i need to retain the array structure for use in a highcharts bar chart. Weird thing is when I console.log in node it looks fine e.g.

```
let example =  [ [ 1536449146000, 0 ], [ 1536450947000, 0 ], [ 1536452748000, 0 ] ]

console.log(example) // [ [ 1536449146000, 0 ], [ 1536450947000, 0 ], [ 1536452748000, 0 ] ]
```

but on the client side when the variable is called on the ejs file `<%= example %>` it becomes :

```
1536449146000,0,1536450947000,0,1536452748000,0
```

and won't render in highcharts. Why is the array losing it's structure like this. All my other variables are working in the ejs tags (single numbers or strings)??

Hope someone can help..

Comment: Because ejs does `example.toString()`, and that's what you're seeing. If you want to output `JSON.stringify(example)`, then write that explicitly.

Comment: Thanks so much  <%=JSON.stringify(example)%> worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bergi kindly pointed out EJS does example.toString() and therefore to keep the array structure you have to do this:

```
<%=JSON.stringify(example)%>
```